# Post hoc fallacy Vs. Slippery slope fallacy

Tags: logic, epistemology, fallacies, difference

What are the differences between [Post hoc fallacy](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_fallacy) and [Slippery slope fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slippery_slope)? **Why they are different?**

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. We discourage one line posts because it is hard to figure out what the poster has in mind and answer that pointedly. In  *post hoc ergo propter hoc* that the "consequence" follows the "cause" is not in question, only that they are causally related is, as opposed to having a common cause or being coincidental. In contrast, in the slippery slope it is not in question that something *can* be a causal link in a chain leading to unintended consequences, only that the circumstances are aligned so that it *will* be is.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.

Comment: Presuming B happens because of A because B happens after A is _post hoc_. Presuming that since A causes B causes C causes D, that A will necessarily cause D is _slippery slope_. Often times the complexity of causation is such that putting many causes and effects together means they "affect or interfere" with each other due to complexity. (It's actually much more complicated than that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to J Ds [comment](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/40730/j-d),

> Presuming B happens because of A because B happens after A is post hoc. Presuming that since A causes B causes C causes D, that A will necessarily cause D is slippery slope. Often times the complexity of causation is such that putting many causes and effects together means they "affect or interfere" with each other due to complexity. (It's actually much more complicated than that.)